# Image doesn't show up in react JS and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I wrote this code in `VSCODE` and I'm trying to show an image which is clipped as a circle, the overflow of the image will be hidden by the circle. But image does not show up. Browser doesn't provide any error as well. image path is correct as it doesn't throw any errors. If you need any further info, I'll add them.

**CSS**

```
 .Pic {
    clip-path: circle(150px at center);
}
```

**React JS**

```
</section> 
<div classname ="Pic">
      <img  width = "150px" height ="150px" src={require("./Assets/profpicjpg.jpg")} alt="" ></img>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: so far I only found the closing tag of img.  <img  width = "150px" height ="150px" src={require("./Assets/profpicjpg.jpg")} alt="" />

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Also, classname. should be className

Comment: @Pretty_Girl : Have updated my Answer, There is another Typo..It should be className not classname

Comment: your div is a block element, and image stands on the left ... far forom the area seen of your div. give your div t& img the same width of your image ;) or something aloke : clip-path: circle(150px at left center); (wich clips a circle of 300px .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `default` after the `require` as below:

```
<img  className="Pic"  width = "150px" height ="150px" src={require("./Assets/profpicjpg.jpg").default} alt="" ></img>
```

Comment: 1 classname TO className.

Comment: 2 add it in <img> not <div>

Comment: image loads, but does not crop to circle

Comment: Ha Ha you can try set circle 50px ,Because the circle is as big as the image, it can't be seen.

Comment: clip-path: circle(50px at center);

Answer (score 0):

You can `import` image first then use in `src` attribute within `img` tag.

There are also some typos in your code:

1. `<section>` Opening section is used as closed section. Use it correctly.
2. `<img></img>`(This is not right). `<img/>` is a un-paired element and should be used correctly
3. Also classname should be `className` (camelcase)

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed the way `clip-path` is not used properly within div, you will need to set `height` and `width` on you parent div element first.

**CODESANDBOX DEMO:** https://codesandbox.io/s/image-issue-yfrgf

**Updated CSS:**

```
img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.Pic {
  clip-path: circle(75px at left center);
}
```

**Correct Code Will be:**

```
import MyImage from "./Assets/profpicjpg.jpg"; // make sure the relative path is correct

<section> 
      <div className="wrapper">
         <img  src={MyImage} alt="An Awesome Image"  className ="Pic"/>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: image loads, but does not crop to circle

Comment: Are you using clip-path syntax correctly..Check once :)